# Git: Rebase basic (Java)

Tags: git, github

I'm working on a git assignment for learning purpose.

My local git repository(repo) name is `linkedlist_java`

The master branch in the local repo has 2 commits and is updated with the remote repo.

The child branch `new_branch`  has 1 commit and is behind the master branch by 1 commit.

**Question**

Using pull rebase command, make the commit on new_branch to be the latest commit over the second commit of master branch.

I did all but still i'm failing the test,

Preliminary local directory checks in local repository... Pass

```
Branch check... Fail

Commits check on master... Pass

Commits check on new_branch... Fail

Checking for pull rebase usage... Fail

Checking for code from master branch... Pass

Checking for code in new_branch branch... Fail

Preliminary remote directory checks in local repository... Pass

Branch check... Fail

Commits check on master... Pass

Commits check on new_branch... Fail
```

Could you please help.

my git URL `https://git-rba.hackerrank.com/git/5b70b6b9-d283-4bab-94fc-a179abd52834`

**Install**

```
bash .install_sh
```

**Test**

```
bash .tester_sh
```

Please help to pass the failing test case

Comment: Have you completed this? if yes please upload the answer

Answer (score 0):

There is an incorrect implementation in tester_sh (Or else it should me mentioned in the question). So for resolving this issue, first of all you have to change your working directory to linkedlist_java folder by:

```
cd linkedlist_java
```

And then, run git commands. *The new_branch has to be created from linkedlist_java directory.*